# Parental control of a child's iPhone without using a second iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, parental-controls, screen-time

I have just set up an iPhone for my child, for which I have created a normal AppleID (with my adult age).

**I would like to limit this phone to only a limited set of apps.** (for example screen-time limits, no social networks apps, etc.)

I tried to set up a parental control with *Settings > Screen time*, this required to create a new person (with child age) in a Family "set up", and it asked for an email address for my child (which I did not want).

Finally, after a lot of steps, the iPhone wasn't restricted to the few apps as I wanted.

I finally understood that, maybe, it would require two iPhones: an adult iPhone which is "master", and the iPhone of my child (as "slave"), which is restricted.

But we only have one iPhone (for my child): other phones at home are not Apple.

Question: **how to set up a parental control (restriction of the device to a limited set of apps) on an iPhone, without having to use a second "adult" iPhone device as controller?**

A list of steps would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to consider a non-Apple product like [Jamf Now](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/) "There are no device minimums. Just a flat price of $4 a month for each device."

Comment: @IconDaemon Do you mean it's impossible to set up an iPhone with parental controls with just one iPhone device (the iPhone itself)? There could easily be a "parent" code that you use to do the setup, and then when no code is entered, you stay in "child" mode. All with just one single iPhone device. Is that possible?

Comment: Jamf Now lets you control your child's iPhone without resorting to having another iPhone for control - that was your use case. We use Jamf Pro at our school for hundreds of laptops and iPads. It is far more granular and powerful than the Apple offerings through parental control. Give it a look. I believe there is a free trial.